# Build tasks and Verification tasks not available in root project when runnig CI with GitHub action

Tags: java, gradle, continuous-integration, build.gradle, github-actions

I am trying to run CI build with Github action for a multi-project containing java modules but keep getting `task ‘clean’ not found in root project ‘${rootProjectName}’`. When I added `./gradlew tasks` to the workflow, the output does not include Build and Verification tasks. Everything works fine on my local machine. See output below:

```
Tasks runnable from root project 'bank-transaction-analyzer'
------------------------------------------------------------

Build Setup tasks
-----------------
init - Initializes a new Gradle build.
wrapper - Generates Gradle wrapper files.

Help tasks
----------
buildEnvironment - Displays all buildscript dependencies declared in root project 'bank-transaction-analyzer'.
dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project 'bank-transaction-analyzer'.
dependencyInsight - Displays the insight into a specific dependency in root project 'bank-transaction-analyzer'.
help - Displays a help message.
javaToolchains - Displays the detected java toolchains. [incubating]
outgoingVariants - Displays the outgoing variants of root project 'bank-transaction-analyzer'.
projects - Displays the sub-projects of root project 'bank-transaction-analyzer'.
properties - Displays the properties of root project 'bank-transaction-analyzer'.
tasks - Displays the tasks runnable from root project 'bank-transaction-analyzer'.

To see all tasks and more detail, run gradlew tasks --all

To see more detail about a task, run gradlew help --task <task>

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 40s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Github_action.yml

```
name: CI-Quality

on: pull_request

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11
      - run: chmod +x ./gradlew
      - run: ./gradlew tasks
      - run: ./gradlew clean check
      - run: ./gradlew assemble
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove settings.gradle from .gitignore

Comment: I do not have this in my .gitignore but still I get this exception.